# UIKit AppDelegate: apply style when app is launched

Tags: swift, uikit, appdelegate

I’m trying to create an app using UIKit and I need to apply a certain theme once my app launches. I do so in the application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) but when I do Theme.apply(to: application.windows.first!) the app crashes with Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

if I remove the Theme.apply line, it all works fine as my storyboard is launch and I see my tab bar controller.
How can I grab the window to which I should apply my theme too?

I’m following https://nsscreencast.com/episodes/382-podcast-app-setup-theming?series=17 BTW, but it’s a bit outdated since it was written for Xcode 10.

Comment: Do u have SceneDelegate in your app, if yes put `Theme.apply(to: window!)` in `func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions)`

Comment: indeed thanks! also, an article that can clarify this change that I wasn't aware of: https://www.donnywals.com/understanding-the-ios-13-scene-delegate/